# 3D bend screen using three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have a canvas and a `three.js` scene. What I want to achieve is to 3D bend the screen/container, just like an old tube tv - I think you get the idea.

In other words, all of my content - which currently solely is a `iframe` displaying another website for test purposes - is supposed to seem bend.

I don't know what an effort this is, hence I'm sorry if that's not appropriate for a stackoverflow question. - Unfortunately I don't even know where to start.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

const perspective = 900;

export default class Scene  {
    constructor($scene) {
        this.container = $scene;

        this.W = window.innerWidth;
        this.H = window.innerHeight;

        this.start();
    }

    start() {
        this.mainScene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.initCamera();
        this.initLights();

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: this.container,
            alpha: true,
        });

        this.renderer.setSize(this.W, this.H);
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    }

    initCamera() {
        const fov = (180 * (2 * Math.atan(this.H / 2 / perspective))) / Math.PI;

        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, this.W / this.H, 1, 10000);
        this.camera.position.set(0, 0, perspective)
    }

    initLights() {
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 2);
        this.mainScene.add(ambientLight)
    }

    update() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));

        this.renderer.render(this.mainScene, this.camera)
    }

}
```

```
<div className="screen__wrapper">
    <iframe className="screen" src="https://tudor-raoul.web.app/de/" width="1000" height="1000"/>
</div>
<canvas id="scene"/>
```

EDIT:
I found the following on github: [demo](https://zz85.github.io/threejs-path-flow/bend.html)
**But how can I apply these three vectors to the whole view to bend all HTML content in one go?**